# Perform a regular expression after a specified character

Tags: unix, awk, sed, grep

I'm trying to ignore a specific character and everything before it, then perform a regex after it.

Example data:

```
Stack103Overflow!Yes:Overflow0204Stack02
```

So lets say I would like the output to be:

```
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack
```

I know the regex to match all digits is [0-9]
However, if performed normally "103" would be matched.

Conclusion:
Ignore a delimiter (in this case, ":") and everything before it.
Perform the regex after the specified delimiter.

What I have attempted:
I've tried reading into "lookahead" and lookbehind" but unable to grasp how to do it. I also can split my data, into 2 files (at the delimiter) so we can have left.txt and right.txt (perform the regex [0-9] on right.txt) then realign with the "paste" command. However this is extremely inconvenient and I've been trying to find a better permanent solution.

My make shift method is:

```
awk -F':' '{print $1" file.txt > l.txt
awk -F':' '{print $2" file.txt > r.txt
# I then open my r.txt in a text editor and remove: [0-9] 
# I then rejoin the file with:
paste l.txt r.txt > fileresults.txt
```

This method is very inefficient and time consuming, I think it's possible to match all occurances of [0-9] after a ":" with a regular expression.

Comment: please update the question to show the actual ***code*** you've tried; what code did you try that included `lookahead` and `lookbehind`? where's the code that performed the `split`, `regex` match and `paste`?

Comment: Done. I haven't tried anything code-related with lookahead/lookbehind I only read.

Comment: lookahead and lookbehind aren't supported by mandatory POSIX tools like awk, sed, and grep (except GNU grep with it's `-P` extension) as they aren't part of the regexp flavors defined by POSIX - [BREs and EREs](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html). So if you want a solution that'll work portably in any POSIX system then it won't use lookaheads or lookbehinds, which you don't need anyway.

Comment: Regarding `I think it's possible to match all occurances of [0-9] after a ":" with a regular expression` - just be aware of the saying [Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/regular-expressions-now-you-have-two-problems/). Many problems are best solved without just a regular expression.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E ':a;s/(:[^0-9]*)[0-9]+/\1/;ta' input_file
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack
```

Comment: You should explain how it works (Learn us fishing, don't give us a fish).

Answer (score 2):

Setup:

```
$ cat file.txt
Stack103Overflow!Yes:Overflow0204Stack02
Some0therL1ne|I'm here 100%:Now where'd I put those 4 cases of s0up
the 3rd line | 123456 some stuff : 1a2b3c4d5e
```

Since OP is already using `awk` we'll look at one idea using a single `awk` call:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {FS=OFS=":"} {gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$2)} 1' file.txt
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack
Some0therL1ne|I'm here 100%:Now where'd I put those  cases of sup
the 3rd line | 123456 some stuff : abcde
```

**NOTE:** assumes each line has a single `:`; if the line has multiple `:`s this solution will only remove digits from the 2nd `:`-delimited field; if a line can contain more than one `:` then OP will need to update the question to state which `:`-delimited fields should be modified

Answer (score 1):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following way let `file.txt` content be

```
Stack103Overflow!Yes:Overflow0204Stack02
1line:with:more:than1colon
linewith0colons
```

then

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{for(i=2;i<=NF;i+=1){gsub(/[0-9]/,"",$i)}}{print}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack
1line:with:more:thancolon
linewith0colons
```

Explanation: I infrom GNU `AWK` than colon is both field separator (`FS`) and output field separator (`OFS`), then for each line I use `for` loop to apply [`gsub`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) removing digits from 2nd (`i=2`) to last (`i<=NF`) field. Independently from how many turn said loop have done I `print` line. Note: input altered to check also other cases: more than 1 colon (2nd line) and not colon at all (3rd line).

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*

Answer (score 1):

Awk does not support lookarounds.

If you can use `gawk`, you can use 2 capture groups. In the first capture group, match the first part including the first occurrence of the colon.

Then match 1+ characters in group 2, and replace all digits with an empty string in this group.

Example source *file*:

```
$ cat file
Stack103Overflow!Yes:Overflow0204Stack02
Stack103Overflow!Yes:Overflow0204Stack02:12:abcd34:test
```

Example Awk

```
awk 'match($0, /^([^:]+:)(.+)/, m){
  print m[1] gensub(/[0-9]+/, "", "g", m[2])
} ' file
```

Output

```
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack
Stack103Overflow!Yes:OverflowStack::abcd:test
```